# Does a Vampire risk Vitae addiction and bond each time they use Taste of Blood on another vampire?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

**Taste of blood** is an ability that lets a vampire gather some information from blood they taste. From VtR2e p. 91:

> In addition to being able to smell blood and
> to identify and track with blood, Kindred discern
> subtle cues from blood they taste.

If vampire uses it on vitae of another vampire, do they risk bond and vitae addiction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VtR2e p. 100:

> Any time a character imbibes a point or more of Vitae, it creates or
> reinforces a blood bond. The bond comes in three stages, usually at
> the first, second, and third drinks.

It seems like it is required to consume a point or more. So, as long as vampire tastes it, but doesn't restore vitae, there is no risk of bond and addiction.

I guess it would make sense to roll for frenzy if Vampire feeds from the source, but it is on ST's discretion.